# how and where can store images with laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

how and where I can store images using laravel?

context:
I want display some images in my main view (these are predefined by me).
I also want to store images uploaded by users, however, do not know where to store these images.

I'd like to call these from the view...

Thank you very much for the help. :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Basically you can save your files wherever you want within your Laravel application provided that you have permissions to create directory and file.

But I prefer saving files in the `storage/app` folder. Laravel provides a simple API to manipulate files on disk. See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem).

---

Update:

This answer was posted when Laravel was in version 5.2.
From version 5.3 on, you can easily create symbolic links by running the  artisan command `php artisan storage:link`. See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem).

Comment: that was the documentation I was looking for . Thank you :)

Comment: @RecoJhonatan make sure you finish this step: "you should create a symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public". After that you can display your images using asset() function in your blade views.

Comment: :) good answer 
but important images, I'd suggest keeping them somewhere safe and not public

Comment: The given answer is somewhat right however very lacking in possible answers. "Basically you can save your files wherever you want within your Laravel application" -> Incorrect. You can put your files anywhere you want as long as you have access to it. It can be a directory, a S3 compatible storage, a ftp server, a smb share.

Answer (score 8):

Make directory for images in myapp/public/images and keep images on there.

```
<img src="{{URL('/images/logo.jpg')}}">
```

Comment: You don't have to use the URL helper function. You can just make it like this: <img src="/images/logo.jpg">

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display them on your site store them in your public directory. Since they are uploaded by users you will need to pass them through a form. Here is an example of a controller.

```
  $file = Input::file('picture');
  $file->move(public_path().'/images/',$user->id.'.jpg');
```

The user will submit a form with a picture field. The two lines above will store it in the public directory in an images folder, with the relevant user's id as its name. Your probably best off making a model in your database for images and their paths. If you do, add these lines after the two above.

```
 $image = new Image;
 $image->path='/images/'.$user->id.'.jpg';
 $image->user_id = $user->id;
 $image->save();
```

To display it in the view simply set an $image variable to the correct image model in your controller and pass it to the view. Then pop its path in the src of the image.

```
 <img src={{$image->path}} alt={{$image->path}}>
```

Comment: Hi, I have a question. That would have implications that the images are stored in the public folder? There could be a way for a malicious user to access the multimedia content without I want?

Comment: Possibly. This is why you only store things like profile pictures here. Sensitive files should be placed in the storage directory.