# img src not getting the image from local disk c:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to get my images from the desktop to my laravel app through img src. Here's the code in my blade file.

```
<img src="file:///C:/Users/Name/Desktop/AISImageFolder/{{$currentUser->image_path}}" alt="..." class="w-100 border-radius-lg shadow-sm">
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The src of an img tag is supposed to be a **URL**, not a file path.

Comment: The [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem) is always a good place to start. Additionally, you could do some research by reading any of the literal thousands of articles to be found online covering this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Laravel, why not store your image files in the Laravel directory instead? It would be a good practice instead of trying to access your files from your Desktop.

May this could help [how-and-where-can-store-images-with-laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256539/how-and-where-can-store-images-with-laravel)